# Maximum execution time for Flyway migrations

Tags: database, flyway

Does anyone has experience with maximum execution time of Flyway migrations

- What is the maximum execition time, if set by Flyway (or this depends on dababase settings primarily)?
- What will happen when this time is hit?
- What if multiple migrations are in chain and one of them timeouts, what will happen?

I have been unable to find any related information in docs or any articles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flyway itself currently does not set a timeout or maximum execution time. The timeout is managed by the target database and the settings on your connection to it.

There is a github [issue thread here on this topic if you would like a timeout to be added and would like to share your scenario with the flyway team](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/887).

What happens when you hit a timeout (or if there is a network or other failure which causes the query to disconnect) will vary depending on how you are using [transactions](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#transactions) and whether your target database supports DDL statements within a transaction.

Comment: Thanks Kendra! Love your videos! :) and dags... :)